# How to determine if disregarding system settings for orientation is bad UX?

Tags: android, device-rotation

Whether I have my Android phone's settings to allow or disallow rotation, the Youtube app always rotates the video to fullscreen when I set my phone sideways.

When searching for this online, I even read somebody say something in the lines of *"It's so great that Youtube doesn't care about that silly rotation setting, when I rotate my phone, I want the video to rotate as well, and go fullscreen!"*.

Well now. Isn't this a huge inconsistency?

I would argue that the system-wide rotation setting should apply to every app, in the same way. And I understand that videos are sort of a "special" kind of content, but a case can be made to want to lock the screen rotation and keep the video fullscreen (landscape orientation) and windowed (portrait orientation) regardless of phone orientation.

**How would one go about determining if this is actually a bad UX design?**
(More than simply soliciting anecdotal opinions and theories that is)

Comment: Does not answer your question, but: sometimes the developers would have to adapt their layout for portrait orientation if their layout is made for a landscape orientation -- that could be more work for them

Answer (score 2):

From a user perspective I can say that it can be a bad UX design. For example when I'm lying in my bed and watching any content I hold my phone naturally in landscape position but I need to display the content in portrait mode. If I cannot force some content to display in portrait, it can be annoying.

I've seen a nice approach in some player apps that were playing videos for both orientations. They had a button, which locked the orientation in the current state. E.g.:
http://www.guidingtech.com/assets/postimages/2014/04/video-player.png